# $JAVA_HOME overwritten, can't use maven

Tags: java, macos, maven

I'm running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.  I have the following relevant lines in ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(jenv init -)"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I don't have a competing .bashrc file or anything else in my home directory.  After I last updated that file I quit and reopened Terminal and got:

```
...$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/Users/myusername/.jenv/versions/system
...$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
...$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/myusername/.jenv/versions/system
```

I assume this is caused by the second line in my .bash_profile; I don't remember why I added it and am hesitant to remove it without knowing what I'm doing.  I don't know why manually rewriting the variable in the terminal doesn't work either.

Either way, my goal is to be able to run maven in the terminal, and when I do I get

```
...$ mvn -v
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: What shell are you using? Zsh?

Comment: It looks like you're using [`jenv`](https://github.com/jenv/jenv). Why not `/usr/libexec/java_home`?

Comment: Anon, I'm using bash.  @trashgod What are you suggesting?  Replacing a line in .bash_profile, and which one with what?

Comment: @FrankHarris: Sorry, I don't know `jenv`; I was hoping the link might help you recall why you added it to your profile. I use `java_home` to set `$JAVA_HOME` _only_ when specifically required by a particular executable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JEnv for managing JDKs. Then you must enable JEnv's maven plugin also enable Export plugin. Don't set `JAVA_HOME` mannuly, JEnv will manage it for you.

Run the following commands and try.

```
jenv enable-plugin export
jenv enable-plugin maven
```